# Rename all files in a directory based on the content of a txt file

Tags: python

I've a text file with a few thousand lines in it:

- line1
- line2
- line3

And a folder with the same number of of `.png` files as lines in the text file.

I'm trying to rename the `.png` files based on the corresponding line in the text file. i.e. `.png` one = `line1` in the text file and so on.

I figure I need to do three different things:

1. Read the text file to generate a list storing the names
2. Loop over each `.png`
3. Rename it based on the list enumeration

I can grab the file names with `glob`, and open the text file and read the lines with `readlines` and I can rename files with `os.rename` using `strip()` to remove the end-of-line character ('\n').

```
path_to_images = glob.glob(r"C:\test*.png")

with open('names.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

os.rename(filename, firstline.strip())
```

What I'm struggling with is how to combine these three pieces into code that actually works.

How do I rename my `.png` files based on the contents of the text file?

Comment: Open them both in the same loop and they should remain in sync

Comment: in your textfile `names.txt` in each line. do the new names also have the file extension or do they come without it?

Comment: good point, they dont

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the textfile (no need for readlines, you can directly loop through `f`) and iterate together with the png files with zip line by line while renaming.

```
path_to_images = glob.glob(r"C:\test*.png")

with open('names.txt') as f:
    for line, file in zip(f, path_to_images):
        os.rename(file, line.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you need. Note I've put the folders based on where my files are. Just change the `current_folder` variable to reflect what you're using

```python
import glob
import os

current_folder = os.path.abspath('.') + '\\rename_files\\'
file_path = current_folder +  'files_to_rename.txt'

with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    for file in list(glob.glob(current_folder + '*.png')):        
        os.rename(file, current_folder + f.readline().strip())
```

Comment: When stepping through this, it ends at the line ` for file in list(glob.glob(current_folder + '*.png')): `  `os.rename` never runs

Comment: if that's happening it could mostly be due to file path. can you try to run the glob part directly and see if it works? I tested the code on my machine and it worked